# Reading cookies from edu\com domains

Tags: asp.net, http

we have a domain that ends in a .edu extension, that sets a cookie.  However at some point, the site hands off to a subdomain with a .com extension that will need to read the cookie..

Example:

- User visits mysite.**edu** sets a cookie
- User clicks a link to take them to subdomain.mysite.**com**

Will I be able to read the mysite.**edu** cookie from subdomain.mysite.**com**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will I be able to read the `mysite.edu` cookie from `subdomain.mysite.com`?

### No

Those are different [top-level domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-level_domain), which is just like asking if a cookie can be read from a different domain (i.e. `http://example.com/` and `http://google.com/`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. and thanks for not just answering "No" :)